# How can initialized array became null?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-activity

Here is the code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);
    setContentView(R.layout.startpage);

    rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();

    //... Filling this array.
}
```

Later, from another activity `StartPage.rowItems.size()` throw `NullPointerException`

It can be 0 (failed to retrieve data or I did `.clear()`), but how, the hell, it became null? I definitely never set it to `null`.
One more point - this array variable is public static and I use it from another activity. Can it be possible android unloads parent activity (what contains all global variables for the whole app)?

P.S. I cannot check it more thoroughly, because this error is not appears in my emulator/devices, but I got reported it on Google Play. So I can't check what was before and when the array became null...

Thank you

More exact code:

```
public class StartPage extends Activity implements View.OnTouchListener {

public static List<RowItem> rowItems;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);
    setContentView(R.layout.startpage);
    rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading data...");
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    pDialog.show();
    gc=new GetData();gc.execute();
}

public class GetData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        rowItems.clear();
        inProgress=true;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);
        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                items = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_COINS);
                for (int i = 0; i < itemss.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = items.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID).toUpperCase();
                    String price = c.getString(TAG_PRICE);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    RowItem item = new RowItem(id, name, price);
                    rowItems.add(item);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        inProgress=false;
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Then call another activity:

```
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        int x = (int) event.getX();
        int y = (int) event.getY();
        int w=view.getWidth()-20;
        int h=view.getHeight()-20;
        if (x<w*0.05 || x>w*0.95 || y<h*0.13 ) return false; // Misclicked

        if (x<w*0.5 && y<h*0.38) {             
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
}
    return true;
}
```

On another activity (MainActivity), try to refresh the listview with the data from main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
void refresh_list() {
    if (StartPage.rowItems.size()>0) {  <-- Here is NPE
    ListAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter(MainActivity.this,R.layout.list_item,StartPage.rowItems); 
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    ((BaseAdapter) getListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Google play report:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at halfprice.coinmanager.MainActivity.refresh_list(MainActivity.java:116)
at halfprice.coinmanager.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:105)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java)
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: It's hard to tell just with the data you provided. You'd need to include any related code with this `ArrayList` and also point out which is exactly the line that threw the `NPE`.

Comment: Maybe StartPage is null, like you said. That'd explain it.

Comment: "parent activity (what contains all global variables for the whole app)" if I understand you right, this is bad design. Holding on to resources in an Activity even after it's no longer on the screen will cause a memory leak.

Comment: KAYSER, This StartPage just called the MainActivity. It should not be null, unless android unloaded it from memory. That's is the question - is it possible (android unloads non front activities from front app?) and if yes, how to prevent it?
neeraj2608, Didn't find better way to pass parameters to inside functions. As well StartPage acts like timed update and retreives data every time, so other activities (what is active right now) can use the updated data...

Comment: Ok, made some investigation of the issue. It seems framework do remove from memory parent activity (if it needs memory) and suppose to call onCreate if the user want to go back to it.
But, by now, any call to StartPage.something will result in NPE.

If I put in MainActivity.onCreate line like
List items = StartPage.rowItems;
will make sure what this array have a pointer from front activity and guarantee android will not touch this array? And latet access to it only with local pointer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are loading your data in static ArrayList and Acessing it to different activity. its not good practice to do.

Let me first tell your answer as you have created this object in Oncreate(). Its better you make create it Globally than this problem will not occure.

Example :

```
public class StartPage extends Activity implements View.OnTouchListener {

public static List<RowItem> rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>(); 

OnCreate(){
   //and perform the action you want to do.  

}
//Hope this will help you definately.
```

**Now Another Method which is the good Practice in Programming language**

Passing data object from one Activity to another is simple, If you want to pass Array object than the object should be serialized. Eg;

```
ArrayList rowItems = new ArrayList();
```

for Passing array object you have to use intent PutExtra, Eg:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);

intent.putExtra("key",array); startActivity(intent);

//intent.putExtra("key",array); will show error if your Model class is not  implements Serializable  eg: public class Model  implements Serializable{

String id;
String price;
String name;
//generate your getter setter and set data in to this.
}

//For getting data in to another class just use

ArrayList<Model> data = (ArrayList<Model>)getIntent().getSerializable("key");
```

Now you can play arround with this data object. You should always try to play around with private or protected object.
Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

If i'm not mistaken:
When your activity is launched, the onCreate() method is called.
But when you come back to the same activity from another activity, then the onCreate method is skipped and onResume() method is called..so my suggestion is to initialize in the onResume() method

```
@Override
protected void onResume(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);
    setContentView(R.layout.startpage);

    rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();

    //... Filling this array.
}
```

Comment: This is not necessarily true. It might happen sometimes, but at the time when you've finished the top `Activity`, maybe the `Android OS` has killed the previous instance of the caller `Activity` because it needed to free memory, thus `onCreate()` will be called instead.

Comment: Thats why its safe to initialize it in the onResume() method cuz even if the activity is creted for the first time...it will still cal the onResume() method after onCreate(), but onCreate() method is not called when ur coming back from another activity

Comment: I don't see logic in this.
If activity destroyed, than onCreate will be called.
If not, the initialized variable should not be null, thus no need to initialize again and no problem...

Answer (score 0):

This answer might not solve your current problem ( not enough code to give a suggestion) but will help you head in the right direction.

Do provide a central data store for your objects, you should consider using singleton design pattern. Also, since  the data will be accessed from multiple threads, you should make the arraylist (in your case) thread safe.

Note: if you are using synchronized list, you should lock the object to prevent access when it is iterated.